# How to calculate the occurrence in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataset

I have this kind of `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

```
                ID_numbers
ID_05698                19
ID_01434                13
ID_06453                12
ID_04697                11
ID_03464                11
...                    ...
ID_01727                 1
ID_00953                 1
ID_01024                 1
ID_06048                 1
ID_06672                 1
```

From this dataset I can see I have exactly one ID with 19 counts (`ID_05698`), another one with 13 counts (`ID_01434`) and so on, but I'd like to have a dataframe which shows me the number of IDs for count, like this:

```
ID_numbers    count
19            1
13            1
12            1
11            2
...           ...
1             5
```

How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: `df['ID_numbers'].value_counts()`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.ID_numbers.value_counts()).reset_index()
df.columns = ['ID_numbers', 'count']
df
```